# Word2vec loss function explodes

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

I'm using the [basic word2vec](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) script from the tensorflow tutorial.

I am running it on a text file of about 100M and it starts of fine, but the loss function explodes after a while.

I would like to better understand how this could happen while I am using negative sampling. Do you think my dataset is too small or could some internal properties be off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience this happens when the learning rate is too large. I experimented with different values and if the learning rate is > 1.0 this happens to me with skip-gram and > 0.5 with cbow.